# SEO for german website - can I use senukeX?

Tags: seo

I'm going to use senukeX to go to the top with small german website...
the problem is -> it's in german and wordpress, social bookmarks, wikis in Senuke are in english.
Does it matter?

Comment: Good luck nuking your site ;) no matter what pyramid scheme you use at some point Google will detect the scheme and your site will forever feel the wrath of the Penguins foot.

Answer (score 1):

You won't get to the top of anything with SEnukeX. And even if you did, you wouldn't stay there for long. Automated, low quality spam.